# Linq and var keyword

Tags: c#, linq

How can i fix a situation like this? I want to use a global 'var latestTests', can i use object or something? This is just a general linqstatement, if i need for more complicated situations as well.

```
 var latestTests =  ????

 if(all == "") {
    latestTests = db.PatientChecklists.Where(x =>
    x.PatientMedicine.Patient.ClinicId == clinicID).OrderBy(x =>         
    x.NextTest).Take(10);
  }
  else {
    latestTests = db.PatientChecklists.Where(x =>
    x.PatientMedicine.Patient.ClinicId == clinicID).OrderBy(x =>         
    x.NextTest);
   }
```

Comment: Why would you want to use a global `latestTests`? What are you going to do with it outside the scope of the if/else context? Assuming you're using `var` because you don't care about the return type in the first place...

Comment: Declare it as `IEnumerable<WhateverIsInPatientChecklists>`

Comment: You can't use var in a situation such as this one. You must specify the type of the variable explicitly. The var-keyword is for cases where the type can be determined implicitly in a deterministic manner.

Comment: ReSharper does a good job here, if I recall. You can simply right-click the `var` and "convert to named type", or something like that. Then you'll know exactly what to use, and can move it to the outer scope.

Comment: If you aren't sure about the type, then (without the `var` definition outside the if/else clause), hover over the `latestTests` variable in Visual Studio and it should tell you the actual type. If it's an anonymous type however (which in your case it isn't), then this kind of thing is more difficult to do.

Comment: Just compile and see what VS tells you. I think you´ll get the answer soon.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have some redundant code there. How about this:

```
var latestTests = db.PatientChecklists
        .Where(x => x.PatientMedicine.Patient.ClinicId == clinicID)
        .OrderBy(x => x.NextTest);

if(all == "")
{
    latestTests = latestTests.Take(10);
}
```

Edit:
In more complicate situations, i wouldn't initialise `var latestTests` in an outer scope. Either by not using `var`, or moving the whole thing in an separate method.

Comment: This is actually the better solution and greatly simplifies the code.

Answer (score 9):

You can't use `var` here, you'll need to declare the object type:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<Foo> latestTests;
```

Though as @AlexH points out, you can simplify your query and remove the need for the outer scope declaration at all.

Comment: You could use `PatientChecklists` instead of `Foo` since he gave it in the code....

Comment: @DrewJordan That's the name of the table, not the type.

Comment: Yeah, I know. it's probably something close though, no? Just saying is all.

Comment: @Rawling If he needs to in his `if-else` clause, he has no choice. Not sure what you mean?

Comment: @Rawling Yes, you're right. Since he has an `if-else` clause anyway. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of the `conditional operator`

```
var latestTests = all != "" ? 
    db.PatientChecklists.Where(x => x.PatientMedicine.Patient.ClinicId == clinicID).OrderBy(x => x.NextTest).Take(10) :
    db.PatientChecklists.Where(x => x.PatientMedicine.Patient.ClinicId == clinicID).OrderBy(x => x.NextTest);
```

Comment: I wouldn't write codes twice like this. As Alex stated about rule #1

Comment: @Kiryl I agree, but OP wrote "This is just a general linqstatement, if i need for more complicated situations as well."